Asynchronous nature of HTMLelement.focus() method
There is a HTML element whose position changes when someone tabs using pseudo-class :focus-visible.
The below code is returning wrong bounding rectangle. After focusing on any element using focus() function, it looks like element is still in not focused state. Both the last two console log are returning wrong answers.
console.log(`Bounding Rectangle for ${tabbedElement}: `, tabbedElement.getBoundingClientRect());
await tabbedElement.focus();
                
let boundingRectTabbedElement = tabbedElement.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(`Bounding Rectangle for after tabbing: `, boundingRectTabbedElement);

let xPath = getXPathForElement(tabbedElement);
console.log(`Bounding Rectangle for after tabbing direct retrieval from DOM : `, getElementByXPath(xPath).getBoundingClientRect());


But when I put a sleep of >= 100ms. It worked as expected.
console.log(`Bounding Rectangle for ${tabbedElement}: `, tabbedElement.getBoundingClientRect());
await tabbedElement.focus();
await sleep(100);

let boundingRectTabbedElement = tabbedElement.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(`Bounding Rectangle for after tabbing: `, boundingRectTabbedElement);

let xPath = getXPathForElement(tabbedElement);
console.log(`Bounding Rectangle for after tabbing direct retrieval : `, getElementByXPath(xPath).getBoundingClientRect());


Can you please help me to understand this behaviour? And it is possible to achieve the same result as below without using sleep and asyn/await function?

What element is tabbedElement? The bounding rect doesn't change because the browser does not render new frames while running JavaScript code. If you pause the script execution (what is sleep()? something like setTimeout()?) the styles update and so bounding rect updates too.

It's there some transition in the styles that could affect the result?

Thank you for your response, @MfyDev. Yes, sleep is something like setTimeout. A tabbedElement is any element that is tabbed, causing its position to change. For example, it can be a button that initially is in the top left corner, but when tabbed, it moves to the center.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Forcing focus inside event handlers is tricky because the normal browser response to various events (like "click", obviously) is to set focus. Thus by using a timer, you force the focus after the browser has done any focus operation itself.

@Pointy, sure. But any better solution than using setTimeout()?

Well you could use Promise.resolve().then(yourcallback) but that doesn't seem significantly more elegant.

To be honest I've always used setTimeout() in this exact situation. It's not pretty but if you spend a lot of time worrying about pretty code in browser JavaScript you're going to be an unhappy person.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus does not return a promise, why do you await it?

Agreed, but still I need to wait to get the action executed. And all of the CSS get applied.
